# Erro GeneXus X Ev3 e Tomcat 7.0.54

Tags: java, tomcat, aplicação-web, sdk, genexus

Estou usando [GeneXus X Ev3](http://www.genexus.com/produtos/download-trial?pt) para gerar uma aplicação WEB com Java e estou usando o SDK 7 Update 55.
Fiz um upgrade recentemente no meu Tomcat para a versão 7.0.54 e passei a ter o seguinte erro no log do Tomcat:

> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/CursoGxParte11JavaSqlLocal]]
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1487)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1465)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1649)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:328)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1374)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.file.Matcher.tokenizePathAsArray(Ljava/lang/String;)[Ljava/lang/String;
>   at com.genexus.webpanels.GXJarScanner.scan(GXJarScanner.java:154) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processJarsForWebFragments(ContextConfig.java:1871)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1259)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:876)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:374)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5355)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)

Alguma ideia??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema esta solucionado a partir do Upgrade 1 da X Evolution 3. 
O GXScanner.jar referencia um método de uma clase que já não esta disponível a partir do Tomcat 7.0.54.

Enquanto não esteja disponível o Upgrade 1, se pode descarregar uma nova versão do GXScanner.jar desde aqui: http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,8,77,O,E,0,,4458

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz um teste com uma aplicação gerada pelo GeneXus X Ev3 usando o Tomcat 7.0.52 e funciona.
Fiz uma instalação do Tomcat 7.0.54 e tive o mesmo erro que você usando a mesma aplicação que funciona com o Tomcat 7.0.52, ou seja, um erro HTTP 404 e no log do Tomcat apareceu um erro do tipo 'Failed to start component'.

Como para mim funcionou com o Tomcat 7.0.52 e você disse que atualizou recentemente para o Tomcat 7.0.54, talvez você possa regredir para a versão 7.0.52 do Tomcat.

Pode baixá-la em http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-7/

Acredito que seja um problema entre essa versão do GeneXus e a versão do Tomcat 7.0.54.